# How to remove dollar sign from WPF Infragistics XamDataGrid Field

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I have a property that is a double and when that property gets displayed on the grid, it defaults to having a dollar sign. How do I remove the dollar sign? I have:

The igWpf Field is where I am having the issue. How do you remove the dollar sign from a double in an igWPF Field?

```xml
<igWpf:XamDataGrid Name="Name"
                    DataSource="{Binding Path=SomeName}"
                    GroupByAreaLocation="None"
                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource LightGrayBorder}"
                    Theme="MetroDark"
                    FontSize="11"
                    ScrollingMode="Deferred">
            
    <igWpf:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
        <igWpf:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" AutoSizeScope="RecordsInView" AutoSizeOptions="Label, DataCells" CellHeight="35" AllowRecordFiltering="True" FilterLabelIconDropDownType="SingleSelect"/>
    </igWpf:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
    <igWpf:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
        <igWpf:FieldLayoutSettings AllowAddNew="False" AllowDelete="False" AutoGenerateFields="False" AutoArrangeCells="Never" RecordSelectorLocation="None" />
    </igWpf:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
    <igWpf:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
        <igWpf:FieldLayout ParentFieldName="SomeName">
            <igWpf:FieldLayout.Fields>
                <igWpf:Field Name="SomeName" Label="ID" Column="0" Width="Auto" />
            </igWpf:FieldLayout.Fields>
        </igWpf:FieldLayout>
    </igWpf:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
</igWpf:XamDataGrid>
```

Comment: Added the code. It is the line:
<igWpf:Field Name="SomeName" Label="ID" Column="0" Width="Auto" />
That when displayed on the UI has a dollar sign on it. I checked the data coming from the C# code and DB and there is no dollar sign. WPF is somehow putting it there.

Comment: Is the field of type decimal or double? Because the XamCurrencyEditor is the default editor for decimal fields.

Comment: This one is a decimal actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default editor for decimal fields is the XamCurrencyEditor. You can change this by setting the Field's EditorType property to use the XamNumericEditor.

```xml
<igData:Field Name="MyField">
  <igData:Field.Settings>
    <igData:FieldSettings EditorType="{x:Type igEditors:XamNumericEditor}" EditAsType="{x:Type sys:Double}" />
  </igData:Field.Settings>
</igData:Field>
```

https://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/f/ultimate-ui-for-wpf/20454/decimal-field-of-object-always-appears-as-a-currency-when-bound-to-xamdatapresenter

Comment: Along these same lines, how would I set the number of decimal places here as well?

Comment: Set the Mask property of the XamMaskedEditor in the FieldSettings.EditorStyle